# How to build an OCR using tessseract.js

Tags: javascript, tesseract.js

I am trying to build an ocr for a html page from the reference 
http://progur.com/2016/10/how-to-use-tesseract-for-ocr-javascript.html

what i did is

```
     <html>
         <head>
             <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/0.2.0/dist/tesseract.js">
  </script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" />
   <input type="button" id="go_button" value="Run" />
    <div id="ocr_results"> </div>
   <div id="ocr_status"> </div>
    </body>
  <script>function runOCR(url) {
  console.log("running")
Tesseract.recognize(url)
     .then(function(result) {
        document.getElementById("ocr_results")
                .innerText = result.text;
     }).progress(function(result) {
        document.getElementById("ocr_status")
                .innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
                    (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
    });
 }
   document.getElementById("go_button")
    .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        runOCR(url);
    });
```

But i am getiing some error saying

worker.js:2610 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'IDBFactory': access to the Indexed Database API is denied in this context.

what am i doing wrong? what should i do to make it work?

Comment: launch chrome with allow file access from file flag. `C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: it doesnt work..